# How to remove the duplicate title tags and duplicate meta descriptions?

Tags: pages, title, seo, duplicates

[image]

Google search console detects my duplicate title tags and duplicate meta descriptions...

I don't know how can I remove them. These two problems are same. It's from same page. My main page and page 2... (please refer to the picture)

I don't know why this is happened...

I'm using Yoast SEO plugin, and I added focus keyword and meta descriptions on the main page... Maybe it's responsible for this problem?

Please tell me how I should do.

Comment: Do you use static page as main page of your site?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Hmmm...I think it's a dynamic page, not a static page. Because actually my website is kinds of travel blog website. So if I write a new post, then main page is changed automatically.

Comment: not exactly what I was asking... I know that this page can change (so it’s dynamic), but... How is it generated? What is set in Settings -> Reading?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Oh...it's set on static page. Should I change to "latest posts"???
And Front page is set on my main page, and Posts page is set on "select." Should I change these?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Oh sorry, Selecting Front page and Posts page are disappeared when I select "latest posts",,,anyway, should I change to "latest posts"???

Comment: No, set it to whatever you want your content to be. That's more important. WordPress doesn't add meta titles or descriptions to pages, so if you have an issue with a plugin adding duplicates you should take it up with the plugin developer.